# Lock multiple tables in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check the state of my data in the database at a given moment in time across multiple tables.

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Activities
(
     ActivityId int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     StateId int NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.States
(
     StateId int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     IsFinal bit NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Requests
(
     RequestId int PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, 
     CreatedUt datetime2(7) NOT NULL
)
```

I'm using a workflow engine. The workflow can have multiple active branches at the same time. Every time the state of an activity changes I notify the engine and start a request. The engine responds to the request with the text activity to be started or "no activity" if there are no more activities **on that branch**. There may be other activities in active states on other branches. When I get the response I delete the request and start an activity if needed.

I need to know when to stop the workflow. That would be when all activities are in final states and no requests exist.

I want to check the states of both tables at the same point in time. I need to avoid race conditions like this ones

1. I check the activities table -> all are in final states (but there is an open request at this time that the code does not know about)
2. The request finishes and ads a new activity and gets deleted
3. I check the requests table and see no request so I wrongfully stop the workflow.

Is there a lock in SQL that I can use to lock both tables before checking them?

Comment: Read about transactions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625/how-do-you-lock-tables-in-sql-server-2005-and-should-i-even-do-it